# R: how to set condition such that all variables are different? a!=b!=c!=d!=e!=f!=g

Tags: r

A simplify problem is that i want to find an assignment such that `DEFG/ABC=9` where `A,B,C,D,E,F,G` are all different.

How do I write

```
a!=b!=c!=d!=e!=f!=g"
```

in R?

My attempt:

```
for(a in 1:9){
 for(b in 1:9){
  for(c in 1:9){
   for(d in 1:9){
    for(e in 1:9){
     for(f in 1:9){
      for(g in 1:9){
       if(((a+10*b+100*c)/(d+e*10+f*100+g*1000))==9 && a!=b!=c!=d!=e!=f!=g)
        print(c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))

#error: unexpected '!=' in:
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `if (length(unique(1:9)) == 9) TRUE`

Comment: @rawr - smart. Should have thought about that.

Comment: `any(duplicated(your_vector))` will tell you if there are any duplicates in your vector.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I think OP needs all to be different, correct? `if (length(unique(c(1:8,8))) == 9) TRUE`

Comment: @rawr, it could be.  It is not clear if they want at least two unique values or all unique values

Comment: How can a three digit number divided by four digit number ever be equal to 9? (0 is not being used here).

Comment: @rnso, sorry it shd have been 4digit/3digit. was a typo. thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
!anyDuplicated(c(a, b, c, d, e, f, g))
```

returns `TRUE` if all values are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3;
vars <- c(a,b,c)
all(combn(vars,2,FUN=function(x) x[1] != x[2] ))
#[1] TRUE
```

And with a failing example:

```
a <- 1; b <- 1; c <- 3;
vars <- c(a,b,c)
all(combn(vars,2,FUN=function(x) x[1] != x[2] ))
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

each pair of variables need to form their own condition, and they need to be joined via `&` (for vectorized) or `&&`

```
 ## Parens added for clarity, but not needed
 (a != b) & (b != c) & (a != c)
```

However, it looks like you are expecting integers, or at least reals, in which case, you can use something like

```
 vars <- c(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
 any(vars != mean(vars))
 # Since any one of the value being different from the group average
 #    indicates that they are all different
```

---

#### Update:

If you want ALL unique values (as opposed to "not all the same value"), you can save yourself quite a few iterations using

```
   for(a in 1:9) {
   for(b in setdiff(1:9, a)) {
    for(c in setdiff(1:9, c(a, b)) {
     for(d in setdiff(1:9, c(a, b, c)) {
      etc ...
```

Comment: I don't think your logic is quite correct.  It seems they want to make sure there aren't any duplicates.  Yours is checking to see if they are all identical.

Comment: @Dason, you could be right. It was't very clear from `a!=b!=c`

Comment: i needed them to be unique. didnt realize how i expressed it wasnt clear until now. Thank you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 ss = c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)   
 for(i in 1:7) for(j in 1:7)if (i!=j) if(ss[i]==ss[j]) 
      { notgood=TRUE; break}
```

But how can a three digit number divided by four digit number ever be equal to 9? (0 is not being used here).

Following code works to produce such 4 and 3 digit numbers:

```
> ss = sample(0:9, 7)
> while(TRUE){
+     num1 = (ss[4]+10*ss[3]+100*ss[2]+1000*ss[1])
+     num2 = (ss[7]+10*ss[6]+100*ss[5])
+     if((num1/num2) == 9 )  cat('\nFound: ',num1,' and ',num2) 
+     ss = sample(0:9, 7)
+     }

Found:  8523  and  947
Found:  8253  and  917
Found:  6489  and  721
Found:  4761  and  529
Found:  5481  and  609
Found:  4608  and  512
Found:  6489  and  721
Found:  3789  and  421
Found:  2781  and  309
Found:  2781  and  309
Found:  5742  and  638
Found:  8613  and  957
Found:  3762  and  418
Found:  5742  and  638
Found:  3762  and  418
Found:  8523  and  947
Found:  8523  and  947
Found:  5823  and  647
Found:  8253  and  917
Found:  1854  and  206
Found:  3762  and  418
Found:  7254  and  806
Found:  7326  and  814
...
```